# Magento image importing problems - CSV

Tags: import, image, csv

So I'm trying to import some images via a CSV to some products in the back end, which are missing images.

Firstly, I have done all kinds of CSV image url formats such as:

```
| image |
/media/import/0/1/0100.jpg
/import/0/1/0100.jpg
/0/1/0100.jpg
/0100.jpg
```

But it is still saying 'Image does not exist' When I'm using the profile importer. As well as, 'Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"'.

However, when trying to access the image from the browser/front end, this particular url works http://www.onestopdiy.com/media/import/0/1/0100.jpg

FYI my csv is laid out like

> sku | image | image_label | small_image | small_image_label |
>   thumbnail | thumbnail_label

Also the permissions to all of the relevant folders is 777.

So I'm at a bit of a loss, can anyone give me any pointers as to what I should check/go over?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to be sure that your images are into */magentoinstallation/media/import/*

Then, your CSV must have this columns at least:
**sku, image, small_image, thumbnail**

If your images are inside of a subfolder, you have to specify it like this in your CSV rows: "*/subfolder/productimage.jpg*". Else, don't forget to add the slash before the image name anyway "**/productimage.jpg**".

Create a new DataFlow profile called "Import Product Images" with the following settings:

- Entity Type: Products
- Direction: Import
- Data Transfer: Interactive
- Type: CSV/Tab Separated
- Field Mapping: sku > sku, image > image, small_image > small_image, thumbnail > thumbnail

Upload your CSV file and Run Profile.

**Source:** My experience, following this tutorial:
http://www.mootpoint.org/blog/magento-bulk-product-import-images/

Comment: Did my answer helped you?